# Equivalent of words appropriate to damage for healing

Tags: nouns, adjectives, synonyms

I'm creating a game and in it, it is possible to damage or heal living things, as you would expect. I've decided that different kinds of things can have one of three reactions to certain types of damage. I also need each reaction to have a noun equivalent.

They can be:

- Resistant/Resistance (Takes less damage)
- Immune/Immunity (Takes no damage)
- Weak/Weakness (Takes more damage)

But they can also be healed. Similarly, healing of a type can be less effective, not effective, or more effective. Is there a similar set of adjective-noun pairs for healing? Preferably they should not sound too 'medical'.

Comment: Homeopathy (no healing), Naturopathy (some healing), Allopathy (complete healing). j/k ill, mending, recovered? Anyway, this is POB.

Answer (score 1):

I think that *resistant* and *immune* could  work just as well in the context of having a beneficial treatment applied, but for "achieves more healing" the term *weakness* is definitely not right; I would suggest *receptive*.  (And if you want a different word than *weakness*, you could also use *susceptible*/*susceptibility*.)

Answer (score 0):

Entities with immunity need no healing power, but entities that nead healing can get three levels of healing:

> - Resurgent/Resurgence--a quick and powerful restoration to **super** strength
> - Resilient/Resilience--a slow but steady restoration to **full** strength
> - Remedial/Remedy--a limited repair of damage to regain **some** strength

Three levels of resistance to damage distributed receiving three levels of healing power, yields nine permutations of result when the healing is applied:

> - **Immune-Resurgent**--damage multiplies power exponentially.
> - **Immune-Resilient**--damage multiplies power quickly.
> - **Immune-Remedial**--damage adds power quickly.
> - **Resistant-Resurgent**--damage adds power slowly.
> - **Resistant-Resilient**--damage has no impact.
> - **Resistant-Remedial**--damage subtracts power slowly.
> - **Weak-Resurgent**--damage subtracts power quickly.
> - **Weak-Resilient**--damage divides power slowly.
> - **Weak-Remedial**--damage kills quickly.

Of course these entities must have a way to share their power. THe strongest must have an Achilles heal, and the weakest must procreate effectively.